# LINQ query, a connection table issue

Tags: linq, foreign-keys, many-to-many, relational-database, erd

I want to write a query that presents for every event (`tbl_events`) all objects (`tbl_objects`) related to it (relation type — M:N).

I have a problem with tables that are connection tables (association class) that holds only foreign keys of the 2 tables that connects.

For instance, `tbl_events` is connected with a connection table named `tbl_object_has_tbl_events` to `tbl_objects`.

Here is a structure of connected tables:

```
tbl events has: eventID, eventName

tbl_object has: objectID, objectName

tbl_object_has_tbl_events: eventID, objectID
```

Here is what I tried to write:

```
IList dataList = (from dEvent in App.glidusContext.tbl_events.
                    join dObject in App.glidusContext.tbl_objects
                    on dEvent.tbl_objects equals dObject.objectID
                    select new { dEvent.eventName, dObject.objectName}).ToList();
```

I can't reach the connection table `tbl_object_has_tbl_events`

How I can implement such query, when I have an M:N relationship?

**UPDATE** Generation of Many-to-many relationship:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table tbl_events
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE tbl_events (
    eventID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    eventName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (eventID));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table tbl_objects
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE tbl_objects (
    objectID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    objectName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (objectID));

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table tbl_objects_has_tbl_events
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE tbl_objects_has_tbl_events (
    objectID INT NOT NULL,
    eventID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (objectID, eventID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_tbl_objects_has_tbl_events_tbl_objects
        FOREIGN KEY (objectID)
            REFERENCES tbl_objects (objectID)
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_tbl_objects_has_tbl_events_tbl_events
        FOREIGN KEY (eventID)
            REFERENCES tbl_events (eventID)
                ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Comment: You mean the table `tbl_object_has_tbl_events` does not show up in the `App.glidusContext` object ?

Comment: Yes. When I type «App.glidusContext.» in VS2010, I don't see «tbl_object_has_tbl_events» in IntelliSense, only basic table, such as tbl_worker, tbl_objects, tbl_events etc. What is the reason of this behaviour? In SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 I can see all connection tables.

Comment: Have you added all the relevant tables in your `.dbml` file in Visual Studio ? Even the link table ?

Comment: Actually, I don't have DBML file at all. I'm using ADO.Net Entity Framework and I got EDMX-file instead. When I generated EDMX-file I choosed all tables, including connection tables. May Be there is some issue in way I declare Many-to-many relation ship? In order to create many-to-many relationship I do: see post update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity data model doesn't show tables that only contain FK's. So in your case the Events entity will have a navigation property Objects and your Object entity will have a navigation property Events.

So to get your information you could write a query like this:

```
IList dataList = (from dEvent in App.glidusContext.tbl_events
                  from dObject in dEvent.Objects
                    select new { dEvent.eventName, dObject.objectName}).ToList();
```